# How to set the non expandable icon

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I am trying to set non expandable icon in FCM notification,
In the image below there are three images in the notification section, first is coming from .setSmallIcon and the expanded is coming from .setLargeIcon , how to achieve the third one which is in the right hand side top corner and always of same size even when expanded
[image]

Comment: That is the `setLargeIcon`

Comment: I am talking about that Disney + hotstar icon with dark blue background , in my case it is getting expanded while expanding the notification , I don't want to expand it rather i want to keep it same size

Comment: Strange, that should be the bigPicture, not the large icon. At least according to https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/expanded